# Realm always automatically sort my list when committing a change

Tags: java, android, realm

I was making a sample realm app for fun. realm version: 0.88.2

The problem I run into is that every time I try to modify my element, my sort setting is automatically gone.

Here is my step:
I have a list of songs.

1. I sort songs by id ASC
2. I click on an item, then a int counter(not id) of this element will be incremented. I commit the transaction
3. Everything is fine.
4. I sort songs by id DSC
5. I click on an item, then a int counter(not id) of this element will be incremented. I commit the transaction
6. The entire list is sorted again by id ASC, which is not expected. I debugged everything I wrote and nothing about sorting was executed.

The code is below:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickInterface {
    @Bind(R.id.tool_bar)
    Toolbar toolBar;
    @Bind(R.id.list)
    ListView list;
    private Realm realm;
    boolean isChecked = false;
    RealmListviewAdapter adapter;
    boolean sort = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        adapter = new RealmListviewAdapter(this, null, true);
        adapter.setListener(this);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (isChecked) {
            updateAllSongs();
        } else {
            realm.where(Song.class).findFirstAsync().asObservable()
                    .filter(new Func1<RealmObject, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call(RealmObject realmObject) {
                            return realmObject.isLoaded();
                        }
                    })
                    .first()
                    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Action1<RealmObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void call(RealmObject realmObject) {
                            if (!realmObject.isValid()) {
                                addUsers();
                            } else {
                                updateAllSongs();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            isChecked = true;
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.tool_bar)
    public void onClickToolbar() {
        if (sort) {
            adapter.getRealmResults().sort("_id");
        } else {
            adapter.getRealmResults().sort("_id", Sort.DESCENDING);
        }
        sort = !sort;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void addUsers() {
        realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                String[] titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.song_titles);
                for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    Song song = new Song();
                    song.set_id(i);
                    song.set_trackNumber(i + 1);
                    song.set_title(titles[i]);
                    song.set_favorite(false);
                    song.set_frequency(0);
                    song.set_lyrics("");
                    song.set_downloaded(false);
                    realm.copyToRealm(song);
                }
            }
        }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                updateAllSongs();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateAllSongs() {
        realm.where(Song.class).findAllSortedAsync("_id").asObservable()
                .filter(new Func1<RealmResults<Song>, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(RealmResults<Song> songs) {
                        return songs.isLoaded();
                    }
                })
                .first()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<RealmResults<Song>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(RealmResults<Song> songs) {
                        adapter.updateRealmResults(songs);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClickedItem(int position) {
        System.out.println("Pressed position " + position);
        Song song = adapter.getRealmResults().get(position);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        Log.d("frequency", String.valueOf(song.get_frequency()));
        song.set_frequency(song.get_frequency() + 1);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        Log.d("frequency", String.valueOf(song.get_frequency()));
        //Log.d("frequency", String.valueOf(_data.get(position).get_frequency()));
    }
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class RealmListviewAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Song> implements ListAdapter{
    private OnClickInterface _listener;

    public RealmListviewAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Song> realmResults, boolean automaticUpdate) {
        super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SongViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.eachsong, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new SongViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (SongViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        Song song = realmResults.get(position);
        viewHolder.track.setText(String.valueOf(song.get_trackNumber()));
        viewHolder.title.setText(song.get_title());
        viewHolder.position = position;
        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateRealmResults(RealmResults<Song> queryResults) {
        super.updateRealmResults(queryResults);
        Log.d("Adapter", "UpdateRealmResults is called");
    }

    public RealmResults<Song> getRealmResults() {
        return realmResults;
    }

    public void setListener(OnClickInterface listener) {
        _listener = listener;
    }

    class SongViewHolder{
        @Bind(R.id.tracknumber)
        TextView track;
        @Bind(R.id.title)
        TextView title;
        @Bind(R.id.freq)
        TextView freq;
        @Bind(R.id.fav_star)
        ImageView fav;
        int position;

        public SongViewHolder(View itemView) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.item_row)
        public void onClickItem() {
            _listener.onClickedItem(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me get this fixed. Thank you so much.

Comment: As a Realm developer, I'll ask you to create a Github issue on this so we can priorities it and solve it.

Comment: Thanks for creating https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2604